# How to debug a custom solr plugin?

Tags: java, solr

I have created a custom solr plugin (with custom analyzers etc..). I wish to debug my code post deployment on the solr server.

Please guide me as to how i can debug my solr plugin? My dev stack is as follows:

Server : Solr 7.2.1
IDE :  Eclipse

Regards,
Namit

Comment: [Have](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/13/how-to-debug-solr-with-eclipse/) you [tried](https://lucidworks.com/2009/09/02/setting-up-apache-solr-in-eclipse/) any [of](http://www.gingercart.com/Home/search-and-crawl/using-eclipse-for-solr-development) the [many](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToConfigureEclipse) resources [about](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-Debug-Solr-With-Eclipse-td4345897.html) how [to](https://github.com/trung/solr-eclipse) do [that](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/running-solr-6-x-in-Eclipse-for-debugging-td4299605.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add this to your server java options:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

And do remote debug from eclipse.

Comment: I tried starting the solr using the following command: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y -jar start.jar. However, as soon as I tried to attached my custom plugin to this socket, the process terminated.

Comment: Ok, this is for Tomcat server. you don't specify how are running solr.

See this guide:

https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/13/how-to-debug-solr-with-eclipse/